# Passing jQuery sortable serialize results to a ASP.NET Razor page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, razor

This is one of those "I figured it out but it was painful so I'm posting this to help others" questions.

I'm building a jQuery based app on ASP.NET Razor. I am using jQuery.ui sortable to enable sorting of things.

It was non-obvious to me how to pass the results of a sortable event to my Razor page. There are lots of examples for PHP, but I couldn't find anything for Razor.

Here's an example jQuery.ui for sortable:

```
    $('#Categories').sortable({
        update: function () {
            var catOrder = $(this).sortable("serialize").toString();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "OrderCategories",
                data: catOrder,
            }).done(function (msg) {
                alert('done: ' + msg);
            });
        }
    });
```

This passes a string that looks like this to the `OrderCategories` page:

```
{id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=1&id[]=4&id[]=5}
```

Apparently ASP.NET is smart enough to figure out a query string like this is an array.  All you have to do to get this array is

```
var order = Request.Params["id[]"];
```

Now `order` is an array of integers representing the order of the list. Took me way too long to figure this out. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above is the answer. Hope this is useful to others.

```
var order = Request.Params["id[]"];
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not rather Request.Params["id"] ? I am just getting null with Request.Params["id[]"]. However, I am getting a string with Request.Params["id"].